# How can I escape curly braces inside jade templates?

Tags: templates, node.js, escaping, pug, curly-braces

ho can I escape curly braces inside a jade teplate?
(I use jade inside node.js)

I want to render jQuery templates to the client. 
The part I want to escape looks like this:

```
div(class='clear')
script(id='BoardListTemplate', type='text/x-jQuery-tmpl')
  <p>${Title}</p>
  <ul id="${Id}" class="IterationBoardList">
    <li class="AddNewItem">Add new Item</li>
    {{tmpl(Items) "#BoardListItemTemplate"}}
  </ul>
script(id='BoardListItemTemplate', type='text/x-jQuery-tmpl')
  <li class="Item" id="${{$data.Id}}">
    ${$data.Description}<br />
    Assigned to: ${$data.AssignedTo}<br/>
  StoryPoints: ${$data.StoryPoints}</li>
script(src='/javascripts/Scrummr.Engine.js', id='BoardListItemTemplate', type='text/javascript')
```

many thanks

Comment: have your tried using the html entities `&#123;` and `&#125;`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to use the pipe ( | ) sign in front of each line inside the script block.

See https://gist.github.com/2047079 for an example.

Comment: I'd like to note that while this answer is helpful and true, it's not actually an answer to the "how to escape curly braces" part of the question.

Answer (score 3):

There are two different things going on here.

Jade uses whitespace to imply document structure; indentation matters and line breaks matter, and Jade expects each line to start with something that it will create HTML tags from.

If you want to feed it something that you don't want it to convert -- for example, raw HTML or script or a raw template you want to render on the client -- you can either

1) start each line with a pipe character ( | ), followed by raw text. Example from [Jade docs](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade#a6-3):

```
p
  | foo bar baz
  | rawr rawr
  | super cool
  | go jade go
```

2) start a raw text block by ending the previous container tag with a period. Example, again from Jade docs:

```
p.
  foo asdf
  asdf
   asdfasdfaf
   asdf
  asd.
```

Separately, Jade performs string interpolation, treating some characters or characters specially, which you may need to escape in contexts where you don't want it to interpolate. This is the part this question asked about (escaping curly braces). Jade doesn't actually treat { specially, but it does treat #{ specially. If you need #{, you can escape it as \#{.

Comment: \#{{search.players}} is what I was looking for... Thank you @metamatt

Answer (score 0):

Jade provides a dot (.) operator at the end of the line that allows you to escape everything inside the child indent block.

```
script(id='BoardListTemplate', type='text/x-jQuery-tmpl').
  // Everything inside here is completely escaped.
  <p>${Title}</p>
  <ul id="${Id}" class="IterationBoardList">
    <li class="AddNewItem">Add new Item</li>
    {{tmpl(Items) "#BoardListItemTemplate"}}
  </ul>

- // outside here it's all JADE.
h1 How about a JADE heading

script(id='BoardListItemTemplate', type='text/x-jQuery-tmpl').
  // back to escaped script in here.
  <li class="Item" id="${{$data.Id}}">
    ${$data.Description}<br />
    Assigned to: ${$data.AssignedTo}<br/>
  StoryPoints: ${$data.StoryPoints}</li>

script(src='/javascripts/Scrummr.Engine.js', id='BoardListItemTemplate', type='text/javascript').
```

The DOT (.) at the end is the important part.